# To Unity Rigidbody move like Character Controller on collision

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody

[image]

I want to a blue ball moving like a figure.

in CharacterController, it was possible.

but in Rigidbody, object was stucked.

help me.

Comment: What's "moving like figure", "object was stuck"?

Comment: i want to move blue ball goes along the path like red line in above figure.

Comment: but when the blue ball has collision to golden ball, a blue ball doesn't move anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a best way is using low-friction physics material.

Answer (score 0):

this is c# code for creating an old school style fps character. First using the ball, attach this script to it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent (typeof (CapsuleCollider))]

public class CharacterControls : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float gravity = 10.0f;
    public float maxVelocityChange = 10.0f;
    public bool canJump = true;
    public float jumpHeight = 2.0f;
    private bool grounded = false;



    void Awake () {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        rigidbody.useGravity = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (grounded) {
            // Calculate how fast we should be moving
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);
            targetVelocity *= speed;

            // Apply a force that attempts to reach our target velocity
            Vector3 velocity = rigidbody.velocity;
            Vector3 velocityChange = (targetVelocity - velocity);
            velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.y = 0;
            rigidbody.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

            // Jump
            if (canJump && Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
                rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(velocity.x, CalculateJumpVerticalSpeed(), velocity.z);
            }
        }

        // We apply gravity manually for more tuning control
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3 (0, -gravity * rigidbody.mass, 0));

        grounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay () {
        grounded = true;    
    }

    float CalculateJumpVerticalSpeed () {
        // From the jump height and gravity we deduce the upwards speed 
        // for the character to reach at the apex.
        return Mathf.Sqrt(2 * jumpHeight * gravity);
    }
}
```

Then, create a camera that is a child of the ball object, and attach this code to the ball's camera.

```
using UnityEngine;

// Very simple smooth mouselook modifier for the MainCamera in Unity


[AddComponentMenu("Camera/Simple Smooth Mouse Look ")]
public class SimpleSmoothMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 _mouseAbsolute;
    Vector2 _smoothMouse;

    public Vector2 clampInDegrees = new Vector2(360, 180);
    public bool lockCursor;
    public Vector2 sensitivity = new Vector2(2, 2);
    public Vector2 smoothing = new Vector2(3, 3);
    public Vector2 targetDirection;
    public Vector2 targetCharacterDirection;

    // Assign this if there's a parent object controlling motion, such as a Character Controller.
    // Yaw rotation will affect this object instead of the camera if set.
    public GameObject characterBody;

    void Start()
    {
        // Set target direction to the camera's initial orientation.
        targetDirection = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;

        // Set target direction for the character body to its inital state.
        if (characterBody) targetCharacterDirection = characterBody.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Ensure the cursor is always locked when set
        Screen.lockCursor = lockCursor;

        // Allow the script to clamp based on a desired target value.
        var targetOrientation = Quaternion.Euler(targetDirection);
        var targetCharacterOrientation = Quaternion.Euler(targetCharacterDirection);

        // Get raw mouse input for a cleaner reading on more sensitive mice.
        var mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        // Scale input against the sensitivity setting and multiply that against the smoothing value.
        mouseDelta = Vector2.Scale(mouseDelta, new Vector2(sensitivity.x * smoothing.x, sensitivity.y * smoothing.y));

        // Interpolate mouse movement over time to apply smoothing delta.
        _smoothMouse.x = Mathf.Lerp(_smoothMouse.x, mouseDelta.x, 1f / smoothing.x);
        _smoothMouse.y = Mathf.Lerp(_smoothMouse.y, mouseDelta.y, 1f / smoothing.y);

        // Find the absolute mouse movement value from point zero.
        _mouseAbsolute += _smoothMouse;

        // Clamp and apply the local x value first, so as not to be affected by world transforms.
        if (clampInDegrees.x < 360)
            _mouseAbsolute.x = Mathf.Clamp(_mouseAbsolute.x, -clampInDegrees.x * 0.5f, clampInDegrees.x * 0.5f);

        var xRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_mouseAbsolute.y, targetOrientation * Vector3.right);
        transform.localRotation = xRotation;

        // Then clamp and apply the global y value.
        if (clampInDegrees.y < 360)
            _mouseAbsolute.y = Mathf.Clamp(_mouseAbsolute.y, -clampInDegrees.y * 0.5f, clampInDegrees.y * 0.5f);

        transform.localRotation *= targetOrientation;

        // If there's a character body that acts as a parent to the camera
        if (characterBody)
        {
            var yRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(_mouseAbsolute.x, characterBody.transform.up);
            characterBody.transform.localRotation = yRotation;
            characterBody.transform.localRotation *= targetCharacterOrientation;
        }
        else
        {
            var yRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(_mouseAbsolute.x, transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up));
            transform.localRotation *= yRotation;
        }
    }
```

This is a very basic first person controller, and is built what the old unity controller was like. i would advise you modify this and build from it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh on the camera object and the ball object you will need to set the camera and body, but when you view the properties in unity you will see the fields to fill in.